# What route is best for comparing diversity between 2 different sites

Tags: anova, t-test, biostatistics, diversity

I am considering fungi presence and diversity in two different forest sites and looking for correlation between fungi presence/diversity and forest health. I am very new to stats, basically know little to nothing - my apologies.

I want to compare diversity and am wondering if I would include zeros in a t-test. Of 175 samples, one site has 54 different species and the other only has 14 so I feel this is a significant difference when considering the diversity in relation to all samples taken (therefore including zeros).

I am also wondering if this is the best route for this kind of data. I also have a shannon weaver index. Thank you so much

- yours, 
  I know nothing about stats.

Answer (score 1):

are you carrying out your analysis in R?  I would recommend doing so, and reading the vignettes on the "vegan" package, particularly the one about "ecological diversity". https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/vignettes/diversity-vegan.pdf

There are a few things to consider with your analysis. Was the sampling intensity the same between your sites? i.e. does the site with 54 species have more than the other site because it is more diverse, or because you sampled it more and so captured more of the diversity. There will always be species that you did not detect (particularly with fungi), so before comparing species richness you might want to either try and estimate the total diversity of your different sites, or more conservatively, rarefy back your sampling so that the sampling intensity matches between sites.

If you want to correlate fungal presence with forest health, then I would suggest building a matrix that shows the abundance of each species at each site. You can then calculate distance metrics that show the similarity, or dissimilarity, of your different sites e.g. Bray-Curtis, Jaccard etc.

You can then use some of the functions in the vegan package to see whether your measures of forest health correlate with changes in the distance metric. For example, have a look at the `envfit` function, which fits environmental variables onto ordination diagrams of your sites (see the intro to ordination https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/vignettes/intro-vegan.pdf)

By the way, you should probably not use t-tests to compare your species richness values. This is count data, so a generalized linear model (poisson family) would work better.

Hope this helps, happy to answer follow up questions.

p.s. I wasn't sure what you meant by your "175 samples"? Are the 'samples' soil cores, or quadrats, or something else?